# biggest intersection of a list with 6 other lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, intersection

so i have 2 lists, one is the following:

```
a = [[('e', 18.019570565395412), ('n', 9.987254997438297), 
      ('a', 7.7558209941102), ('r', 6.6337526622659), 
      ('i', 6.600725745328597), ('t', 6.501644994516685), 
      ('o', 6.348366226166633), ('d', 5.847034563938841), 
      ('s', 4.446777970199559), ('l', 3.72314975166299)], 
     [('e', 12.106222485002089), ('t', 8.957697044103082), 
      ('a', 8.370584890241286), ('n', 7.607979302319451), 
      ('o', 7.490104957124618), ('i', 7.3906837841807365), 
      ('s', 6.619604800837547), ('r', 6.519995330217634), 
      ('h', 4.5520963180272425), ('l', 4.174559477586928)], 
     [('e', 17.355137469595004), ('s', 8.143220837795097), 
      ('a', 7.8767560437690145), ('n', 7.549126676263891), 
      ('i', 7.163346641798983), ('t', 7.009814697935651), 
      ('r', 6.939253827661279), ('l', 5.823753838298597), 
      ('u', 5.566685341067845), ('o', 5.494351584605674)], 
     [('e', 11.726720365453488), ('i', 11.143857839435189),
      ('a', 10.481789164283027), ('o', 8.879509290276063), 
      ('n', 7.433536567715994), ('l', 6.861989205859677), 
      ('t', 6.660947684470068), ('r', 6.473326474063275), 
      ('s', 5.332336897171472), ('c', 4.1076677341515335)], 
     [('e', 16.01393585408341), ('n', 10.010042012501282), 
      ('i', 7.874987191310585), ('r', 7.499538887181063), 
      ('a', 6.538374833487037), ('s', 6.393687877856339), 
      ('t', 6.1842401885439084), ('d', 5.152577108310278), 
      ('u', 4.3455272056563174), ('l', 3.962701096423814)], 
     [('e', 13.02338360095244), ('a', 11.820318700775383), 
      ('o', 9.20172171683253), ('s', 7.635081506807498), 
      ('n', 7.547469320471335), ('i', 7.219915745772025), 
      ('r', 6.704927040722877), ('l', 5.650833384211491), 
      ('d', 5.098296599303987), ('t', 4.7109103119848585)]]
```

which is a list containing 6 sub-lists
the other list i have is:

```
b = {'e': 1636, 'a': 930, 'd': 581, 'i': 507, 'g': 298, 'h': 222, 'c': 145, 'b': 117, 'j': 104, 'f': 74}
```

i need some code that does the following:

1. tells me which sub-list of a has the biggest intersection with b
2. prints the index of that sub-list

important remark: i only care about the keys in each list(the strings), the values dont have to match up. so by intersection i really mean: how many keys does the list b have in common with each sub-list of a.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the sublists in `a` into dictionaries and `b` into a dictionary; then use `set.intersection` on the dictionary keys to get the size of the intersections:

```
intersection_sizes = [len(dict(s).keys() & dict(b).keys()) for s in a]
```

Output:

```
[10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10]
```

Then another list comprehension to flush out the index of subsets with the largest intersection:

```
index_of_the_subsets = [i for i, x in enumerate(intersection_sizes) if x == max(intersection_sizes)]
```

Output:

```
[0, 5]
```

Comment: that code seems to work, there is a small issue though: i have never turned a list into a dictionary. how would i go about doing that?

Comment: @BrahimEssadiki `dict(b)` constructs a dictionary; then `dict(b).keys()` gets the keys. Also, this works because each sublist is a list of tuples so the dict constructor works on each