# coding the cardinality of the intersection of 1 list with 6 other lists

Tags: python, list, intersection

i got the following data:

```py
a = [('e', 1636), ('n', 991), ('a', 930), ('t', 678), ('o', 677), ('r', 612), ('d', 581), ('i', 507), ('l', 405), ('s', 399)]
```

and:

```py
b = [[('e', 18.019570565395412), ('n', 9.987254997438297), ('a', 7.7558209941102), ('r', 6.6337526622659), ('i', 6.600725745328597), ('t', 6.501644994516685), ('o', 6.348366226166633), ('d', 5.847034563938841), ('s', 4.446777970199559), ('l', 3.72314975166299)], [('e', 12.106222485002089), ('t', 8.957697044103082), ('a', 8.370584890241286), ('n', 7.607979302319451), ('o', 7.490104957124618), ('i', 7.3906837841807365), ('s', 6.619604800837547), ('r', 6.519995330217634), ('h', 4.5520963180272425), ('l', 4.174559477586928)], [('e', 17.355137469595004), ('s', 8.143220837795097), ('a', 7.8767560437690145), ('n', 7.549126676263891), ('i', 7.163346641798983), ('t', 7.009814697935651), ('r', 6.939253827661279), ('l', 5.823753838298597), ('u', 5.566685341067845), ('o', 5.494351584605674)], [('e', 11.726720365453488), ('i', 11.143857839435189), ('a', 10.481789164283027), ('o', 8.879509290276063), ('n', 7.433536567715994), ('l', 6.861989205859677), ('t', 6.660947684470068), ('r', 6.473326474063275), ('s', 5.332336897171472), ('c', 4.1076677341515335)], [('e', 16.01393585408341), ('n', 10.010042012501282), ('i', 7.874987191310585), ('r', 7.499538887181063), ('a', 6.538374833487037), ('s', 6.393687877856339), ('t', 6.1842401885439084), ('d', 5.152577108310278), ('u', 4.3455272056563174), ('l', 3.962701096423814)], [('e', 13.02338360095244), ('a', 11.820318700775383), ('o', 9.20172171683253), ('s', 7.635081506807498), ('n', 7.547469320471335), ('i', 7.219915745772025), ('r', 6.704927040722877), ('l', 5.650833384211491), ('d', 5.098296599303987), ('t', 4.7109103119848585)]]
```

i want to be able to display the cardinality of the intersection of a with each sub-list of b.
just to be clear: i need 6 outputs: the cardinality of the intersection of list a with 1st sub-list of b......list a with 6th sub-list of a. by intersection i mean the tuples in a and sub-list of b need to have the same key, the values are irrelevant. the output is preferably a list like this: [1, 3, 5 , 4, 2, 8]

Comment: You asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71849187/biggest-intersection-of-a-list-with-6-other-lists) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71858602/intersection-of-2-objects-of-different-types). What's wrong with the answers you got there?

Comment: @enke datatype differs, plus i misunderstood what i needed to do: i need to calculate all 6 intersections instead of the biggest one

Comment: @timgeb basically yes, however only the keys need to match, also the order doesnt matter

Comment: this question is exactly like your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71849187/biggest-intersection-of-a-list-with-6-other-lists). In fact just copy pasting the answer there works on this current question.

Comment: Can lists have duplicate keys and how would they count in an intersection (only once, like in sets, or according to their count)?

Answer (score 0):

If the lists can't have duplicate "keys" just collect the length of the key-set intersections:

```
set_a = {e for e, _ in a}
result = [len(set_a & {e for e, _ in list_b}) for list_b in b]
```

Otherwise use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)s:

```
from collections import Counter

count_a = Counter(e for e, _ in a)
result = [sum((count_a & Counter(e for e, _ in list_b)).values()) for list_b in b]
```